# Speculations and deductions

Tags: grammar, adverbs, modal-verbs

I am very curious to know if:

> “ She probably should have had the cake"

is grammatically correct.In other words Iam in doubt whether we can use adverbs of certainty, like *probably*,  along with modals of speculation, like *should*.

Comment: _Should_ and _probably_ are both modals. Using two modals together mixes their senses and provides ample opportunities for ambiguity.The more modals you use, the less clear the probability. But it's quite grammatical; just not very clear semantically.

Comment: I'd take 'should' here as deontic. This still leaves open the possible readings 'In my estimation, the panel should have awarded her (not Alex) the cake' and 'I think that she should have brought the cake along (and it's no wonder the party organiser was less than impressed)'. Epistemic 'She bought seventy percent of the lottery tickets. With the first prize being that wonderful cake, I'm not surprised. I left before the draw so I don't know who won what, but she probably should have had the cake,' requires quite a bit of context to be reasonable.